# How to call a predicate from another predicate - Prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate

I have this predicate:

```
start:-
  write(‘Type your numbers:’),
  read(L1),
  call(oc([L1],N)). % Point 1   <=====
```

`oc` is another predicate like this:

```
oc([],[]).
oc([H|T],[[H,X]|Y]):-
  count(H,[H|T],X), 
  deleteall(H,T,T1), 
  oc(T1,Y).
```

How can I do this?

When I am at Point 1 and use `call`, the value on `L1` variable is not working.
When I run this code I receive the message `true`. The function `oc` is not running.
How can I call the `oc` function and pass the value stored in `L1`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please do not double [post](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/how-to-call-a-predicate-from-another-predicate/541?u=ericgt) questions without linking, it is bad etiquette.